# pyqt5 how do I stop a function from running before gui starts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to this so be patient.(english is not my main language so if there are typos then I'm sorry.)

I want to get the gui to start and load before the function starts.

[Program Showcase of the problem](https://youtu.be/-TCNQEpWJwY)

The problem I have is that the function starts in the console first and then I have to stop it before the gui can start, after I have done all that then everything works as it should.

**Edit:**

the options panel in the main window picture gets the text from a method inside the functions file with a print statement and is therefore not interactible, that's why I have an input function in the optionsPicker() just to clarify.

the gui code:

```
import sys
import io
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("welcome.ui", self)
        self.continueButton.clicked.connect(self.goToMenu)

    def goToMenu(self):
        mainMenu = MainMenuScreen()
        widget.addWidget(mainMenu)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class MainMenuScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenuScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("mainmenu.ui", self)
        self.setOptionsField()
    
        self.out = self.output
        self.inBar = self.inputBox
    
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.process.setProgram(sys.executable)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.on_readyReadStandardOutput)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.on_readyReadStandardError)
        self.inBar.editingFinished.connect(self.on_editingFinished)
    
    def runFile(self, url):
        self.process.setArguments([url])
        self.process.start()

    def setOptionsField(self):
        self.options.setText(getMethods())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        out = self.process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.out.insertPlainText(out)
        self.output.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_readyReadStandardError(self):
        err = self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.out.insertPlainText("\n" + err)
        self.output.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_editingFinished(self):
        self.process.write(self.inBar.text().encode() + b"\n")
        self.inBar.clear()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_F5:
            self.output.clear()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = WelcomeScreen()
window = MainMenuScreen()
window.runFile("Assignments_2.py")  #reads and executes the function
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.addWidget(window)   
widget.setFixedHeight(800)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)    
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is the function it's calling from a different .py file:

```
 def optionsPicker():
    while True:
        options = input("\nPick an option: ")

        match options:
            case "0":
                stringMethods()
            case "1":
                randomNumbers() 
            case "2":
                distanceBetweenPoints()
            case "3":
                distanceBetweenPointsDialog()                
            case "4":
                calcVolOfSphere()
            case "5":
                roundOffAndCut()
            case "exit":
                break
            case "":
                print("Invalid Option! Try again.")
                continue
optionsPicker()
```

pictures of how the gui looks:
[welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAEPu.png)
[main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ5jg.png)

Comment: You could: 1. call the function after everything on your window has been set; 2. Use a `QTimer` to run the function 1ms later. By using a `QTimer`, Qt automatically schedules the function to execute later on. Though, if you're using a GUI, calling `input` will freeze the GUI which might be bad. If you need some user input, you could use a `QInputDialog`.

Comment: @CarlHR how do I call the function after everything has loaded?

as mentioned I'm new to python and PyQt.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to edit and remove the 1st option, but I couldn't edit the comment anymore, because of the 5min timeout. To execute a function after everything has been rendered you could use a `QTimer.singleShot`. But calling `input()` to get user input data *will freeze the GUI*, so beware about using it.

Comment: @CarlHR check the "Program Showcase of the problem" link to see the issue.

Comment: If `optionsPicker()` is only executed when you *press Enter* on the `QLineEdit` from the user interface, why not connect `QLineEdit.returnPressed` to `optionsPicker`? It would get rid of the while-loop (so no need for threading anymore), and when you don't need to execute `optionsPicker` anymore, just call `QLineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect(...)`.

Comment: @CarlHR optionsPicker() executes automatically when the program starts and then I have to write "exit" in the terminal to stop the loop, then the gui loads the welcome screen where I have to click continue to get to the main screen where the options list, input and output is.

the function works inside the gui but the problem is that I have to break the loop to get inside the gui, so is there a way to get pass the step of stopping the loop to get inside the program?